# Multiple update operation in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update multiple fields in a single document using Mongoose.

```
var fooSchema = new Schema({
  foo: {
    a: [ { type: Number, ref: User, required: true } ],
    b: [ { type: Number, ref: User } ],
    c: [ { type: Number, ref: User } ],
  }
});

foo.findByIdAndUpdate(
 req.params._id,
 { 
   $addToSet: { "foo.a" : req.params.user_id },
   $pull: { "foo.b" : req.params.user_id },
   $pull: { "foo.c" : req.params.user_id } 
  },
  { safe: true },
  function(e) {
    ...
  }
);
```

`foo.a` is updated as expected but user_id is not removed from `foo.b`.
Is it possible to have multiple update condition in a single operation using Mongoose/MongoDB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to combine both `$pull` terms into a single object as you can't have two fields with the same name:

```
foo.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.params._id,
  { 
    $addToSet: { "foo.a" : req.params.user_id },
    $pull: {
      "foo.b" : req.params.user_id,
      "foo.c" : req.params.user_id 
    } 
  },
  { safe: true },
  function(e) {
    ...
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it specified in the documentation?

Comment: @JohnJohnGa It's more of a standard limitation of any JavaScript object (or more generally, any associative array or hash).